# Mixing "script." and "include" in Jade

Tags: javascript, pug

I have a Javascript template in Jade:

```
script.
 bla
 bla
```

I wish I could include some js code coming from a file called 'inc.jade' containing just this:

```
bli
```

It seems that this code fails:

```
script.
 bla
 include inc.jade
 bla
```

What is the correct way to include inc.jade into my script. tag ?

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion for this scenerio: 
**You should put your JS into each seperate file and include that js file where ever required.**

The latest release of Jade adds mixins and includes,you can include existing jade as :

```
html
      include includes/head  
      body
        h1 My Site
        p Welcome to my super site.
        include includes/foot
```

---

```
    includes/foot.jade:        
    #footer
      p Copyright (c) foobar
```

---

```
    includes/head.jade:        
    head
      title My Site        
      script(src='/javascripts/jquery.js')
      script(src='/javascripts/myCustom.js') <<------- include it where you need
      script(src='/javascripts/app.js')
```